# How does Jenkins credentials work or apply to agent in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've following two pieces of code one work and other doesn't. I need to understand if the `agent` is declared inside the stage, credentials are recognised and if the the `agent` is declared on top/global level, then credentials don't work and ends un in error. Could anyone help understand why it is so and how this can be worked out?

Error:

```
pipeline 
{
    environment {
    DOCKER_REGISTRY='xxxxxxxxx'
    DOCKER_CREDENTIAL='dcaas-r'
  }
  agent 
  {
     docker { 
     image "xxxxxxxxx/dotnet:latest"
     registryUrl env.DOCKER_REGISTRY
     registryCredentialsId env.DOCKER_CREDENTIAL
     reuseNode true
     }
  }    
    stages 
    {
        stage('Test') 
        {
            steps 
            {
                sh 'dotnet --version' 
            }
        }
    }
}

Error response from daemon: Head "xxxxx/dotnet/manifests/latest": unknown: Authentication is required
```

Success:

```
pipeline 
    {
        agent any
        environment {
        DOCKER_REGISTRY='xxxxxxxxx'
        DOCKER_CREDENTIAL='dcaas-r'
      }
   
        stages 
        {
            stage('Test') 
            {
               agent 
               {
                  docker { 
                  image "xxxxxxxxx/dotnet:latest"
                  registryUrl env.DOCKER_REGISTRY
                  registryCredentialsId env.DOCKER_CREDENTIAL
                  reuseNode true
                  }
               } 
                steps 
                {
                    sh 'dotnet --version' 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What could be done, in order to not to write same `agent` block in all `stages`?

Comment: If you have a global `agent` directive, then you do not need to specify the values as environment variables because 1. they are not environment variables 2. they are only used once 3. they are not dynamic. That solves your problem also.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks for the explanation, and it worked. Another question, while `agent` is now global directive, I don't see the logs of docker image being pulled. Earlier while `agent` was in `stage`, I was seeing all the logs. How can I see the logs of image being pulled ?

Comment: You will only view logs for the `stages`, and so global directives are not logged.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks! make sense now. I'd like to mark your solution as 'Answer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a global agent directive, then you do not need to specify the docker values as environment variables because

- they are not environment variables
- they are only used once
- they are not dynamic

It would appear like:

```
agent {
  docker { 
    image                 'xxxxxxxxx/dotnet:latest'
    registryUrl           'xxxxxxxxx'
    registryCredentialsId 'dcaas-r'
    reuseNode             true
  }
}
```

You will only view logs for the stages, and so global directives are not logged. This means you will be unable to see image retrieval logs for the docker `agent` in the global directive.